# PERCENTILE_DISC but using less than or equals in AWS Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, quantile, percentile

The function `PERCENTILE_DISC` is equivalent to use

```
pandas.quantile(q=P, interpolation='higher')
```

Redshift documentation states:

> PERCENTILE_DISC Window Function
>   PERCENTILE_DISC is an inverse distribution function that assumes a discrete distribution model. It takes a percentile value and a sort specification and returns an element from the given set.
>
> For a given percentile value P, PERCENTILE_DISC sorts the values of the expression in the ORDER BY clause and returns the value with the smallest cumulative distribution value (with respect to the same sort specification) that is greater than or equal to P.

How can I get the equivalent for lower? is possible Redshift devs just overlook 'lower' case?

```
pandas.quantile(q=P, interpolation='lower')
```

Comment: Hint:  `ORDER BY . . . DESC`.

Comment: this is clear as water for you,  so I need to use P=1-P and then ORDER BY DESC? I will try